# Conditions to get 2 real negative roots for a 3rd order polynomial

Tags: polynomials

What is the conditions required to make the 2 roots of the 3rd prder polynomial 
$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ real and negative, if  $a<0$ and $d>0$.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried on this problem? In what context did you encounter this?

Comment: Since $\frac da \lt 0$ is the product of the roots, you will have to have all three negative.  Do you know what $\frac ba$ and $\frac ca$ are as functions of the roots?

Comment: @RossMillikan but they will not be necessary real

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is motivated by getting a condition for the intersection of 2 ellipses.
The conditions are :
$b < 0 $ and 
$\Delta > 0 $
 where  $\Delta=18 a b c d-4 b^3 d+b^2 c^2-4 a c^3-27 a^2 d^2; $ is the discriminant.
First condition is obtained via routh-criteria and guarantee that we have 2 negative roots, and the second guarantee that all the roots are real.